# Get Average Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Hoping someone can help me with the LINQ syntax to calculate an average.  For example, I have the following LINQ query:

```
var rates = from rating in ctx.Rates  
            where rating.Id == Id  
            select new 
            {   
                UserId = rating.UserId,  
                Rating = rating.Rating  
            };
```

If 10 records are returned, I need to calculate average on the Rating field.  It is defined as as a Double in my DB.  I am using LINQ to EF.  So I would be assigning the UserId, MiscId, and the Rating would be the average on the records returned.  I am passing one object back to the client code.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Are you looking for an average rating per user id?  If so, then you need to use both [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx) and [Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358946.aspx).

```
var rates = ctx.Rates
               .Where( r => r.Id == Id )
               .GroupBy( g => g.UserId, r => r.Rating )
               .Select( g => new
                {
                   UserId = g.Key,
                   Rating = g.Average()
                });
```

Answer (score 102):

```
double RatingAverage = ctx.Rates.Where(r => r.Id == Id).Average(r => r.Rating);
```

Answer (score 2):

This could also work if you don't want to calculate the average separately and rating is from another table

```
var query = (from u in db.Users 
                     where rating.Id == Id
                     select new ViewModel
                     {
                         UserId = rating.UserId
                         Rating = (from c in db.Comments where c.fkUserId.Equals(u.Id) select c.StarRating).Average()
                     }).ToList();
        return query;
```

It will return rating average.
**Note:** Use Rating as nullable double type i.e. `double? Rating`