# Getting average value of groups with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to split my List into different groups based on a certain value each item in the List has, and then find the average of another value in those groups.

To better put it, I have a list of Students:

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student> {
    new Student { Name="Bob", Level=Level.Sophomore, GPA=3.2f },
    new Student { Name="Cathy", Level=Level.Freshman, GPA=3.6f },
    new Student { Name="James", Level=Level.Senior, GPA=3.8f },
    new Student { Name="Jessica", Level=Level.Senior, GPA=3.7f },
    new Student { Name="Derek", Level=Level.Junior, GPA=2.8f },
    new Student { Name="Sam", Level=Level.Junior, GPA=3.1f }
};
```

And I want to group them by their Class Level, so they'll be grouped into Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, and Senior. And then I want to be able to get the Average GPA for those groups.

So a possible result set for these students would be:

```
Senior: 3.7
Junior: 2.9
Sophomore: 3.2
Freshman : 3.6
```

I'm not quite too sure how to go about getting this result though. I have tried things like `students.GroupBy(x => x.Level).Average();` but it does not work.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Average Using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590704/get-average-using-linq)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to use an additional `Select`, so you're looking for something like this:

```
var result = students.GroupBy(s => s.Level)
                     .Select(g => new {Level=g.Key, Avg=g.Average(s => s.GPA)});
```

---

`Select(g => new {...})` creates an instance of a new anonymous type for each group.

That type has two properties:

- `Level`, which is the `Key` property of the group
- `Avg`, which is the average GPA of the group

Just "imagine" there's this type in use (more or less):

```
class GroupAverage
{
    public Level Level { get; set; }
    public float Avg { get; set; }
}

var result = students.GroupBy(s => s.Level)
                     .Select(g => new GroupAverage { Level=g.Key, Avg=g.Average(s => s.GPA) } );
```

but it simply has no name.

---

`result` is now:

[image]

Feel free to round the values if you need to.

---

To get the `Level` with the highest average, simply use

```
var highest = result.OrderByDescending(a => a.Avg).First().Level;
```

(Note that this will crash if there are no items in `students`)

Comment: Can you explain what this query is doing? I don't quite understand the new {Level=g.Key, Avg=g.Average(s=>s.GPA)} so well.

Comment: He is selecting an anonymous object out of his previous group, with 2 properties: 1 the Key of the grouping, which is the level. The 2nd property is an aggregation on the grouping, in this case he takes the average value of all students GPA in this grouping.

Comment: It's grouping by Level and then Selecting a new anonymous object containing two values, the key value (generated by the group() function) and the average of the GPA.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thank you! Would I still be able to select the group with the highest GPA if I so chose?

Comment: @user3113376 - With enough time and money you could do anything, including ordering by GPA descending and taking 1 item (or the first one). I would suggest that you download http://www.linqpad.net/ and go through the excellent sample code that comes with LINQPad. It will really help your understanding.

Comment: @sloth I would like to see about just getting the group name first, so in this case, Senior would be the one I would get back, as it has the highest GPA.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
students.GroupBy(s => s.Level, s => s.GPA, 
                (level, scores) => new { Level = level, Avg = scores.Average() }
```