# How can I do a group by and then an average using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class:

```
public class LogViews2
{
    public string DateYYMMDD { get; set; }
    public double CPUSpeed { get; set; }
    public double DBSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

Which I am filling with data:

```
var ViewsList2 = ViewsList
    .Select(x => new LogViews2
    {
        DateYYMMDD = x.DateYYMMDD,
        DBSpeed = x.DBSpeed,
        CPUSpeed = x.CPUSpeed
    })
    .ToList();
```

Instead of just using a select, I would like to group by DateYYMMDD and then for each get an average of the DBSpeed and CPUSpeed and have this sorted in date order.

Can anyone give me advice no how I could do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting average value of groups with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28426740/getting-average-value-of-groups-with-linq) This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590704/get-average-using-linq) is also an exact duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var ViewsList2 = ViewsList
    .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select(g => new LogViews2
    {
        DateYYMMDD = g.Key,
        DBSpeed = g.Average(gx => gx.DBSpeed),
        CPUSpeed = g.Average(gx => gx.CPUSpeed)
    })
    .ToList();
```

Edited as per @Pavel Anikhouski : simplified `Average` call.

And added `OrderBy`

Comment: `g.Average(gx => gx.DBSpeed)` looks more natural

Comment: `.OrderBy(item => item.DateYYMMDD)` : "...and have this sorted in date order..."

Comment: @DmitryBychenko why you are adding ``()`` to ``g => new LogViews2``?

Comment: @Sajid: we *create* a new intance of `LogViews2` class: `g => new LogViews2()` and then *initialize* it: `{DateYYMMDD = ..., }`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko yeah, i understand this, but i don't know what is the difference between ``new LogViews2{....}`` and ``new LogViews2(){....}`` here?both calling the default constructor!

Comment: @Sajid: ah! Sorry, I was too judgemental `new LogViews2 {...}` is *also possible*, syntactic sugar: c# tolerate argument list `()` skipping

Comment: @Renat - How about the OrderBy?

Comment: @Alan2, edited with `OrderBy`

Comment: @Renat - Thanks.  Works good.  I want to change it slightly but will create another question in next ten mins.

Answer (score 1):

Could try, off the top of my head:

```
ViewsList.GroupBy(logView => logView.DateYYMMDD)
         .Select(logView => new {
             AverageCPU = logView.Average(log => log.CPUSpeed),
             AverageDBSpeed = logView.Average(log => log.DBSpeed)
         }
);
```