# Calculating Average with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, average

I am trying to write a query with Linq to calculate for a genre of a movie for a user (the most watched for that specific user) the average ranking of the movies for that genre (the rankings are in a different table and are given out by many users and I need to calculate the average ranking for each and every movie in that genre).

my scheme is this:
[image]

my code by now is this:

```
var extractMoviesAndTheirGenre =
                        from item in results join second in database.MovieGenres on item.movieId equals second.movieId
                        where item.movieId.Equals(second.movieId)
                        select new
                        {
                            MovieId = item.movieId,
                            GenreName = second.Genre.genreName,
                            GenreId = second.genreId
                        };
        var extractGenreNeeded =
                        from item in extractMoviesAndTheirGenre
                        group item by new
                        {
                            GenreName = item.GenreName,
                            GenreId = item.GenreId
                        }
                        into grouped
                        select new
                        {
                            GenreId = grouped.Key.GenreId,
                            GenreName = grouped.Key.GenreName,
                            CountGenre = grouped.Count(x => x.GenreId == grouped.Key.GenreId),
                        };
        extractGenreNeeded = (extractGenreNeeded.OrderByDescending(x => x.CountGenre).Take(1));
    var GenreId = extractGenreNeeded.FirstOrDefault().GenreId.ToString();
        var extractMoviesInFoundGenre =
                        from item in extractGenreNeeded
                        join second in database.MovieGenres on item.GenreId equals second.genreId
                        where second.genreId.Equals(GenreId)
                        select new
                        {
                            MovieId = second.movieId
                        };
        var extractingMoviesInGenreAndTheirAvarageRank =
                        from item in extractMoviesInFoundGenre
                        join second in database.UserMovieRanks on item.MovieId equals second.movieId
                        select new
                        {
                            MovieId = item.MovieId,
                            Rank = second.movieRank
                        };
```

As you can see, I was able to Isolate the most watched genre for the user(I get the list of movies watched by that user as an input to the query and this input is named results of type IQueryable) I am unable to calculate for each movie in that genre its average score...

Thank you,

Comment: Why don't you give a meaningful name to your variables ? it would be easier for you and for us to understand your code.

Comment: You might see [Get Average Using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4590704/2026740)

Comment: I edited my code for your convenience... Daniel I read it and it was of no use to me cause its not my case..

Comment: How would you have don't this i pure SQL. Start there and work backwards.

Comment: In SQL I would just put an average on that column in the Having clause or something... I don't have that here.. help would be appreciated... I would'nt of asked if I had a clue how to do that with LINQ...

Answer (score 0):

You already have the Ranks for each Movie, so after your code

```
var extractingMoviesInGenreAndTheirAvarageRank =
        from item in extractMoviesInFoundGenre
        join second in database.UserMovieRanks on item.MovieId equals second.movieId
        select new
        {
            MovieId = item.MovieId,
            Rank = second.movieRank
        };
```

you should get the average, in this case with a lambda expression:

```
double avg = extractingMoviesInGenreAndTheirAvarageRank.Average(x => x.Rank);
```

Also, if you just want the average for every user, and don't care about `MovieId`, you could do everything in your first query:

```
var extractingMoviesInGenreAndTheirAvarageRank =
        (from item in extractMoviesInFoundGenre
        join second in database.UserMovieRanks on item.MovieId equals second.movieId
        select second.movieRank).Average();
```