# Convert SQL query with GroupBy and Avg to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a simple query in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    l.State,
    AVG(ls.Amount) As StateAvg
FROM 
    LeadSales ls 
    JOIN  LEADS l on ls.LeadID = l.LeadID
GROUP BY 
    l.State
```

This works:

[image]

Having a little trouble converting this to LINQ (where `query` is an IQueryable of the `LeadSales` table)...

```
var StateList = from q in query
                 group q by new
                 {
                      q.Lead.State,
                      q.Amount // <--- it this corrcect?
                 } into g
                 select new AverageLeadSalesPriceItem
                 {
                      StateCode = g.Key.State,
                      StateAverage = ????
                  };
```

With:

```
public class AverageLeadSalesPriceItem
{
    public string StateCode { get; set; }
    public decimal? StateAverage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Average Using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590704/get-average-using-linq)

Comment: /\ @Pikoh I looked at that one, but could not make that answer work.

Comment: How is query defined in c#?

Comment: @jdweng good question.  I edited my OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not far off. The group clause should group by the same fields you would group by in SQL, and then the grouping construct object `g` acts like an Enumerable/Queryable of its own, containing all rows of the group, that you can call aggregate functions on. So, with only one field defining the group key, there's no need for an anonymous type, and then you simply call Average() on `g`, defining the projection identifying the field to average.

```
var StateList = from q in query
             group q by q.Lead.State into g
             select new AverageLeadSalesPriceItem
             {
                  StateCode = g.Key,
                  StateAverage = g.Average(gq=>gq.Amount),
             };
```

Remember that your Linq query, if based on a Queryable provider like an EF DbSet, doesn't execute against the database until you indicate that you need "real" in-memory objects, either implicitly by calling a method that returns one or more said objects (First(), ToArray() etc) or explicitly using the AsEnumerable() extension method.

Answer (score 2):

This will be smth like

```
var StateList = from q in query
                 group q by new
                 {
                      q.Lead.State
                 } into g
                 select new AverageLeadSalesPriceItem
                 {
                      StateCode = g.Key.State,
                      StateAverage = g.Average( a=>a.Amount )
                  };
```

Note that if you want to calculate aggregates dynamically (like in SQL) you can use specialized library like [NReco PivotData](https://www.nrecosite.com/pivotdata/dynamic-data-aggregation-and-grouping.aspx) (I'm developer of this library, it is free for single-deployment projects).