# I'm trying to translate this sql query on Linq to sql query, but i have some difficult on Avg() and DateDiff()

Tags: sql-server, linq, average, datediff

```
select  AVG(DATEDIFF(yyyy, (p.BirthDay), GETDATE()))
from Person p
```

I'm trying to translate this SQL query in a Linq to SQL query. My problems is with AVG() and DATEDIFF().

Comment: Instead of trying to translate it, try thinking about what it is doing and think about ways to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590704/get-average-using-linq  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/calculate-age-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also DATEDIFF(yyyy,p.Birthday, GetDate()) returns the number of New Year's Eve's the person has seen, not their age.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

EF6

```
double resultAverage = ctx.Person.Average(p => DbFunctions.DiffDays(p.BirthDay, DateTime.Now));
```

EF4

```
double resultAverage = ctx.Person.Average(p => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day" ,p.BirthDay, DateTime.Now));
```

tryAlso

```
double resultAverage = ctx.Person.Average(p => (DateTime.Now - p.BirthDay).Days);
```

Answer (score 1):

**I SOLVED doing like below: **

```
var query = (from A in ctx.Persons
             select new {
             AverageAge = ctx.Persons.Average(p => (Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")) - Convert.ToInt32(p.BirthDay)))
             }).Distinct();
```

> NOTE: i have solved it like above because p.Birthday returns a string in "yyyy" format.

Or i could do it also by applying "Take(1)" instead of "Distinct()" like below:

```
var query = (from A in ctx.Persons
             select new {
             AverageAge = ctx.Persons.Average(p => (Convert.ToInt32(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")) - Convert.ToInt32(p.BirthDay)))
             }).Take(1);
```