# Calculate average for grouped field using c# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, average

There are someone can help me for calculating an average using c# Linq, for the folowing data :

```
Year    city1   city2   value  
2016    CIT01   CIT01   578
2016    CIT01   CIT02   1067
2016    CIT01   CIT03   17
2016    CIT02   CIT01   1105
2016    CIT02   CIT02   233
2016    CIT02   CIT03   0
2016    CIT03   CIT01   1425
2016    CIT03   CIT02   231
2016    CIT03   CIT03   1398
2017    CIT01   CIT01   185
2017    CIT01   CIT02   69
2017    CIT01   CIT03   2225
2017    CIT02   CIT01   0
2017    CIT02   CIT02   104
2017    CIT02   CIT03   258
2017    CIT03   CIT01   10
2017    CIT03   CIT02   342
2017    CIT03   CIT03   643
2018    CIT01   CIT01   59
2018    CIT01   CIT02   163
2018    CIT01   CIT03   284
2018    CIT02   CIT01   19
2018    CIT02   CIT02   379
2018    CIT02   CIT03   462
2018    CIT03   CIT01   46
2018    CIT03   CIT02   0
2018    CIT03   CIT03   154
```

In example, I would like to get average of :
2016    CIT01   CIT01   578
2017    CIT01   CIT01   185
2018    CIT01   CIT01   59

Output:

```
Year   city1   city2   value
-----------------------------
Prev    CIT01   CIT01   274
Prev    CIT01   CIT02   433
Prev    CIT01   CIT03   842
Prev    CIT02   CIT01   375
Prev    CIT02   CIT02   239
Prev    CIT02   CIT03   240
Prev    CIT03   CIT01   494
Prev    CIT03   CIT02   191
Prev    CIT03   CIT03   732
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Average Using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590704/get-average-using-linq)

Comment: Please do some searching before asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This link does not process many or nested grouped fields at the same time

Comment: Your question does not mention "many or nested grouped fields". It literally asks how to calculate the average for a grouped field, which is what the proposed duplicate answers. See [the help center for more information on what you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: Why did the value for `Year` become `Prev` in the expected results?

Comment: @HereticMonkey "Calculate average for grouped field using c# LINQ" <> "Get Average Using LING", I mentioned "for grouped field"

Comment: @RufusL it's just for the example, I could put 2019

Comment: So... like the article I linked to says, [edit] your question with more detail of how this question differs. You're going to have a better time on this site if you write more explanation of your question. Get into details; how are calculating the average that's different from the obvious (i.e., the answers in the duplicate)?

Comment: I still don't understand why the `Year` would become `2019`, then? Shouldn't it remain the same year as the data that's being presented? Trying to understand your grouping rules here, and the output doesn't make sense...

Comment: it's a kind of prevision, the average of all previous years

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to group by the `city1` and `city2` values, and select a new item where the year is `"Prev"`, the cities remain the same (as in the group) and the value is the `group.Average(g => g.value)`. We can use the `Math.Ceiling` method to force rounding up (as you have in your example).

For example, given the following class to hold data:

```
public class Data
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string City1 { get; set; }
    public string City2 { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public Data(string year, string city1, string city2, int value)
    {
        Year = year;
        City1 = city1;
        City2 = city2;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Year} {City1} {City2} {Value}";
    }
}
```

And the following `List<Data>` to hold the initial values from your question:

```
var allData = new List<Data>
{
    new Data("2016", "CIT01", "CIT01", 578),
    new Data("2016", "CIT01", "CIT02", 1067),
    new Data("2016", "CIT01", "CIT03", 17),
    new Data("2016", "CIT02", "CIT01", 1105),
    new Data("2016", "CIT02", "CIT02", 233),
    new Data("2016", "CIT02", "CIT03", 0),
    new Data("2016", "CIT03", "CIT01", 1425),
    new Data("2016", "CIT03", "CIT02", 231),
    new Data("2016", "CIT03", "CIT03", 1398),
    new Data("2017", "CIT01", "CIT01", 185),
    new Data("2017", "CIT01", "CIT02", 69),
    new Data("2017", "CIT01", "CIT03", 2225),
    new Data("2017", "CIT02", "CIT01", 0),
    new Data("2017", "CIT02", "CIT02", 104),
    new Data("2017", "CIT02", "CIT03", 258),
    new Data("2017", "CIT03", "CIT01", 10),
    new Data("2017", "CIT03", "CIT02", 342),
    new Data("2017", "CIT03", "CIT03", 643),
    new Data("2018", "CIT01", "CIT01", 59),
    new Data("2018", "CIT01", "CIT02", 163),
    new Data("2018", "CIT01", "CIT03", 284),
    new Data("2018", "CIT02", "CIT01", 19),
    new Data("2018", "CIT02", "CIT02", 379),
    new Data("2018", "CIT02", "CIT03", 462),
    new Data("2018", "CIT03", "CIT01", 46),
    new Data("2018", "CIT03", "CIT02", 0),
    new Data("2018", "CIT03", "CIT03", 154),
};
```

We can group the data and select new items using this `System.Linq` code:

```
var results = allData
    .GroupBy(d => new {d.City1, d.City2})
    .Select(group => new Data("Prev", group.Key.City1, group.Key.City2,
        (int) Math.Ceiling(group.Average(g => g.Value))))
    .OrderBy(d => d.City1)
    .ThenBy(d => d.City2);

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**Output**

[image]